# How to determine the inverse Z-transform using partial fraction?

Tags: z-transform

Task: Determine the inverse z-transform of a discrete-time system
represented by the rational expression below using the partial fraction
expansion method. The impulse response of the system is absolutely
summable.

This is what I did:

[image]

Was I able to get the values for the partial fraction correctly? What do I do after this?

I'm stuck :( Thank you for your help!

Comment: Stick some numbers in and see if it's the same. This isn't EE btw, it's math.

Comment: This is more suited for dsp.ee, but you're close to the treasure: \$h[n]=A_0\delta[nT]+\sum_i^Nu[nT-T]A_ip_i^{n-1}\$. Where \$A_i\$ are the residuals and  \$p_i\$ the poles.

Comment: A quick google search discusses this topic in detail. You should be able to deduce and apply to your problem ...

Comment: Not asked, but in the middle, when you made H(z)/z, you didn't divide -16 by z in the nominator expression.

Comment: @user287001 Oh yeaaa thankyou!!

Comment: @citizen I'm sorry, what I found were all complicated for me, that's why I was hoping someone will be able to explain it easier here :(

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Hmmm I'm confused T_T I'll try to read more about this. Thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the advice! And ohh okay, sorry for that! I saw someone posting here about z-transforms so I thought I was in the right place